# How to remove navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I want to remove the navigation drawer from my **fragment_login** and **fragment_create_account** fragments. I removed the bottom navigation and toolbar from these fragments using addOnDestinationChangedListener with the following code for toolbar:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            when(destination.id) {
                R.id.loginFragment, R.id.createAccountFragment ->
                    toolbar.visibility = View.GONE
                else -> toolbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
```

Similarly, for bottom navigation:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            when(destination.id) {
                R.id.loginFragment, R.id.createAccountFragment ->
                    bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE
                else -> bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
```

I tried to do the same (same code as above for drawer layout) with navigation drawer but it didn't worked and turned the whole application blank. Any help is appreciated.

MainActivity.KT

```
package com.example.integratedmodulateoroperationroom

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.*
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.findNavController()

        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(R.id.homeFragment, R.id.loginFragment),
            drawer_layout
        )

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            when(destination.id) {
                R.id.loginFragment, R.id.createAccountFragment ->
                    toolbar.visibility = View.GONE
                else -> toolbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }

        bottom_nav.setupWithNavController(navController)
        val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_nav)

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            when(destination.id) {
                R.id.loginFragment, R.id.createAccountFragment ->
                    bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE
                else -> bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }

        nav_view.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return item.onNavDestinationSelected(navController) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

activitymain.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_backgroud"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_nav"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_nav_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

nav_grah.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/loginFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.example.integratedmodulateoroperationroom.HomeFragment"
        android:label="Integrated Module OR (Operation Room)"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_otFragment"
            app:destination="@id/otFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_surgicalFragment"
            app:destination="@id/surgicalFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_laminarFragment"
            app:destination="@id/laminarFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/otFragment"
        android:name="com.example.integratedmodulateoroperationroom.OtFragment"
        android:label="OT Lights"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_ot" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/surgicalFragment"
        android:name="com.example.integratedmodulateoroperationroom.SurgicalFragment"
        android:label="Surgical Lights"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_surgical" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
        android:name="com.example.integratedmodulateoroperationroom.SettingsFragment"
        android:label="Settings"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/laminarFragment"
        android:name="com.example.integratedmodulateoroperationroom.LaminarFragment"
        android:label="Laminar Airflow"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_laminar" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
        android:name="com.example.integratedmodulateoroperationroom.LoginFragment"
        android:label="Login"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_homeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homeFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
            app:popUpTo="@id/homeFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_createAccountFragment"
            app:destination="@id/createAccountFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/aboutFragment"
        android:name="com.example.integratedmodulateoroperationroom.AboutFragment"
        android:label="About"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_about" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/createAccountFragment"
        android:name="com.example.integratedmodulateoroperationroom.CreateAccountFragment"
        android:label="CreateAccountFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_create_account">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_createAccountFragment_to_loginFragment"
            app:destination="@id/loginFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/loginFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Comment: You don't, just lock it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did not knew was that I had to **lock** the navigation drawer. So, by using

```
drawer_layout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)
```

I successfully hid the navigation drawer. So, for making it appear in the rest of the fragments I used the code below:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            when(destination.id) {
                R.id.loginFragment, R.id.createAccountFragment ->
                    drawer_layout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)
                else -> drawer_layout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what are you trying to do, but you can remove it by deleteing the menu.xml in the resources/menu file.

Don't forget to clean the XML and classes to avoid any errors.

If you are trying just to hide them from the UI you can do that by setting the visibility.

Another way is to remove the setting the menu up from the hosting screen.

Comment: Actually I have multiple fragments and I am trying to remove it from only two fragments. I tried the to set the visibility but then the whole application went blank... It would be great if you could show how to set the visibility... I think I might be doing something wrong

Comment: Maybe you should create a call back to tell the hosting screen to hide the bottom navigating if this fragment was appearing to the user.